# Saving datatime format from java or rails to mysql?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ruby, calendar

```javascript
function formatDate(Day, Month, Year) {
    Month++;
    // adjust javascript month
    if (Month < 10) Month = '0' + Month;
    // add a zero if less than 10
    if (Day < 10) Day = '0' + Day;
    // add a zero if less than 10
    var dateString = Year + '/' + Month + '/' + Day;
    return dateString;
}
```

I've this function on a file `calendar.js` to save in a specific format a selected date, i need to save on `mysql` this date in a `datetime` format.

In the `app/views/feeds/_form.html.erb` file there's this `f.time_select:date` to save the time , so how can we save on `mysql` the data from the `calendar.js` file or better from the form file using maybe `f.data_select` ?

Comment: what params it is sending to the controller?

Comment: Your `JavaScript` function on its own is too little information to answer your question. Could you provide some HTML to provide the context (e.g. what fields it is generating) or at least the whole view this is in? I guess you would need some `jQuery` magic to make this work. The controller action to actually save your data would be the next step with the `params` hash in between as @G.B suggested.

Comment: is using the javascript required? If not, have you looked into f.select_date? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers

Comment: Maybe `Time.strptime('2014/04/04', '%Y/%m/%d')` in ruby code on the server side